# SQL select with 'date' type column, how to ignore year?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have still problems with MySql xD.

I will have an price_table for each day of the year (**MySql** with PhpMyAdmin). So i generated an 365 rows table D: and now i do some select within a range, like this:

```
  SELECT * FROM `rprices` WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2022-02-01' AND '2022-02-30'
```

But now i figured out that the date type column requires also an year value :D ... now i need to do something like this query (#2), i dont really like the idea of creating 365/364 rows for each year

```
  #2) SELECT * FROM `rprices` WHERE `date` BETWEEN '02-01' AND '02-30'
```

Is this possible? 
Or it will be better to create and table with month,day column? Perfomance?

Thanks, 
i will reply as soon as possible if you ask something i will be online to 2:00 GTM+1

Comment: You ask about performance. Extracting month or day from a date makes it non-sargable, which will lead to shocking performance, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable. This is not addressed in the answers below. If your table is non-trivial in size, you might want to consider a separate and indexed month column or even a partition by month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can just strip the year out with date functions like MONTH and DAY

if you are just going to do from the first of the month to a specific day then do this.

```
SELECT * FROM rprices
WHERE MONTH(date) = 2 
 AND DAY(date) <= 20
```

if you want to range it between two days in the month that aren't the beginning and end then do this.

```
SELECT * FROM rprices
WHERE MONTH(date) = 2 
 AND (DAY(date) BETWEEN 5 AND 20)
```

It is much better to store a date as an actual date type and not store it in multiple columns..
I would recommend you keep the date column as is and just do different functions on the date.. you can add indexes if there are issues to improve performance

As noted in the comments you don't even need to filter by day since you are including the whole month

```
SELECT * FROM rprices
WHERE MONTH(date) = 2
```

Comment: And the performance implications the OP asks about?

Comment: I got it! Perfomance is ok i have an "little" table with only 8030 rows :D I will continue  to use Date type columns beacouse i have other queries that works with date.

Comment: I think that it will be correct to use  'BETWEEN 1 AND 31)' instead 'BETWEEN 1 AND 30)' to get all days of the month...my example was wrong D_:

Comment: @Kharchi you can change it to whatever you need it to be.. your desired query had 30 so thats what I used :)

Comment: Yes i know :D i have noticed an little performance upgrade with this... instead of 0.0006 of previus query now i got 0.0005 in avarege xD

Comment: Why does the day matter anyway, if you only care about the month? The performance of this query will be horrific for a larger table.

Comment: @john well it doesn't matter for this query but in case the op would like to filter by day then that's what this query would be able to do

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below mentioned sample query and modify the same as per your need:

```
SELECT * FROM rprices WHERE MONTH(date) BETWEEN '2' AND '3'
AND DAY(date) BETWEEN '1' AND '31'
```

Comment: your answer is basically the same as mine and its 8 minutes after my answer.. please try to make your answers more unique... and even though MySQL will convert the string number to an INT when comparring to the INT that is returned from MONTH() and DAY() its best to just put in the INT instead of a string number

Comment: Why exactly are your numbers strings?

Comment: '2' and '3' are like strings because of quotes, right?

Comment: Er, yes, and month(date) returns a number.

Comment: @johnbarca MySQL is smart enough to convert them... But thats just extra overhead

Comment: I tested i php so : var_dump('2') = string(1) but if i do var_dump(2) = int(2); Date columns works with numbers so if we use the numbers witouth quotes we will "help" MySql :D